# Screenshot feature in chat like snagit and greenshot in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm learning nodejs and i implemented a basic chat application in it using socket.io .

What i'm trying to do is add share screen shot feature in that chat
while i'm able to do the browser screen share using library
[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

I further want to enhance it to share even the desktop screen capture. I know the scope that web application reach is within the browser's window, but how can i extend.

I don't want code i want to know the approach for it, in proper way

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking to achieve is using WebRTC: https://bloggeek.me/implement-screen-sharing-webrtc/

WebRTC enables two clients to connect directly and stream two-way communication between each other, including data. Similar to WebSockets, but allowing for more streaming functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extension have access to screen shot API of the desktop. You can ask you users to install you extension.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

You can inspect the source code of an example extension that doing it: https://github.com/AminaG/OpenScreenshot, or just install it from the Chrome web streo: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-screenshot/akgpcdalpfphjmfifkmfbpdmgdmeeaeo

(I created this repo)